# Can't create project in sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm having trouble creating a project in my sonarqube instance - it's like there are projects already created that I cannot see.

I login as the admin user, go to the Administration -> Projects -> Projects Management page, and then click Create Project.

I give it a name, and then when I type in my maven project name in the key field, e.g. *au.com.foo:project-bar* and click create, I get the message that

> "Could not create Project, key already exists: au.com.foo:project-bar"

Thing is, when I look at the list of all projects on that project management screen, there is no project with that key. There is also nothing under Provisioned and nothing listed under Ghosts either.

What gives? I would have thought if there was a previous unsuccessful project with that key it would have been listed under the ghosts section anyhow. I'm also definitely logged in as admin here, so should see everything?

Comment: What do you see when you go to https://<your_server_name>/dashboard/index?id=au.com.foo:project-bar ?

Comment: Something utterly bizarre - I'm taken to a login page where I try to login, both as a user and then as an administrator, and then both times I am told "You are not authorized to access this page. Please log in with more privileges and try again." How do I get more privileged than admin? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found a workaround - not a particularly nice one, mind you. I opened up the Sonar database and had a look in the PROJECTS table:

```
select * from projects where kee like 'au.com.foo:project-bar%'
```

This revealed a couple of old entries from a previously (unsuccessful, I guess - there was no files indexed against these entries) attempt to analyse the project. Doing a delete from the table of these entries then enabled me to create the project in Sonar again.

Why the entries didn't render on the UI in the first place is anyone's guess.